# Arduino + ESP8266 to send MQTT messages

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, mqtt

I'm wondering if an Arduino Uno (or any other 328 family) that connects via Serial to an ESP8266 can send MQTT messages, rather than AT commands.

Answer (score 2):

*I didn't use MQTT yet so I didn't try any of the following options. I only know they exist.*

1. AT firmware version 2 has a set of [AT commands for MQTT](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/esp32/AT_Command_Set/MQTT_AT_Commands.html). But development of [AT 2 for esp8266](https://github.com/JAndrassy/WiFiEspAT#at-2-1) was ended with version 2.2. It requires an esp8266 with a 4 MB flash.
2. a very old esp8266 firmware called [ESPLink](https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link) has support to register to a MQTT topic and then use it in Arduino with [the EL-link library](https://github.com/jeelabs/el-client). (The main goal of the ESPLink firmware was OTA update for Uno)
3. PubSubClient library is a very popular Arduino library for MQTT. It works over any standard Arduino networking library. For esp8266 there are multiple options for a firmware+library combination. I can only recommend my WiFiEspAT library (all others have too many problems). WiFiEspAT works with AT firmware in esp8266. Best is to use [AT 1.7.5](https://github.com/JAndrassy/WiFiEspAT#at-17-1) or the 'fake' AT firmware [ESP_ATMod](https://github.com/JiriBilek/ESP_ATMod), which is an Arduino sketch.

The third option will take much more flash and RAM than the first two, but it is a standard and portable way. You can port it to other networking library or other MCU type.

EDIT: Another option is to write a sketch with MQTT for the esp8266 directly and communicate the data with Uno or not use the Uno at all.